# Sending messages to Amazon MSK (Kafka) from Laravel app

Tags: laravel, apache-kafka

I have a laravel app that sends produces messages on to a kafka topic. I am sending the messages to Amazon MSK. I am using the mateusjunges/laravel-kafka ([documented here](https://junges.dev/documentation/laravel-kafka/v1.13/producing-messages/5-publishing-to-kafk)) package for sending messages to kafka. The code for sending the messages looks like

```
$message = new Message(
            headers: ['producer' => config('app.name')],
            body: $message,
        );

        $sasl = new Sasl(
            username: config('app.KAFKA_USERNAME'),
            password: config('app.KAFKA_PASSWORD'),
            mechanisms: config('app.KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM'),
            securityProtocol: config('app.KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL'),
        );

        $producer = Kafka::publishOn($topic)
            ->withMessage($message)
            ->withSasl($sasl);

        $producer->send();
```

The message is being send to Kafka but for some reason the message is not delivered immediately to the MSK cluster, it takes some time to view the message on MSK. How can I solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Kafka producers buffer data in memory to reduce network traffic; calling send doesn't actually "send over the network", rather to a queue, which will later get sent.

Depending on the library, there's a flush method on the producer client to actually send and block with a network call